# What is this $ExternalData_1 supposed to mean in Excel PowerPivot and PowerQuery?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, powerpivot

I am using Excel 2016 to clean my dataset using PowerQuery.

Let's say the data table is in `Sheet1`, and the cleaned data table produced by PowerQuery is `Sheet2`.

Now when I try to import the table in the `Sheet2` to PowerPivot, the Table Import Wizard showed this:

```
Sheet2 

Sheet2$ExternalData_1
```

Both of which look identical to me, and I just can't see the difference between them, but I don't want to choose the wrong source here. To avoid needless problems in the future, can anyone enlighten me what's the difference between them and which one should I choose as my source table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to load the data directly into a pivotable instead of creating a new table and its pivotable. It will reduce the error of choosing the wrong one.

[image]

Comment: Hi @virtualdvid, thanks so much for answering. The problem is I use the table generated by the the power query as a data source for PowerPivot data model in another file. Any idea for this situation? Thanks again!

Comment: You can connect and process all the data that you need in a single file with multiple queries linked to multiple sources in PowerQuery. Then in the options check `add this data to the Data Model` and `Only create connection` for each query all the results will be in PowerPivot.